# Python cmd module command aliases

Tags: python, cmd, command-line-interface

I am making a command line interface in Python 3.1.1 using the cmd module.

Is there a way to create a command with more than one name e.g. "quit" and "exit"?
Or would it just be a case of making a number of commands that all reference the same function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it would just be a case of making a number of commands that all reference the same function.

This is common.  It often helps to provide multiple common aliases for a command.  It makes the user's life simpler because the odds of them guessing correctly are improved.

Comment: From a performance issue would it be a bad idea to have a lot of them or is it negligble?

Comment: You'd never be able to measure the difference.  It's just class method dispatching -- which uses a hashing algorithm -- so the complexity is **O**(1).  Adding a few extra method functions or having one method function call another involves microscopic overhead.